# ActiveScaffold or ActiveRecord how to search on an associated model's column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, activescaffold

I have following models

```
Customer: name:string, phone:string
has_many :sales

Sale: amount:float, item_name:string
belongs_to :customer
```

Now in `ActiveScaffold` I get a simple single line input box to search for sales.

What I need to do is, be able to search sales by the customer name as well.

There should be a way to do this with `ActiveScaffold`, or atleast with native active record functionality.

One way I can think of is, adding the customer name as a column and populate it along with sale while it is created.Not sure what the best approach to achieve this should be.

Edit: Adding info from comment:

Is it possible to define something like

```
Sales 
searchable_columns :amount, :association => {:customer => name}, :as => yumyum_column
now when i search by 
Sale.where(:yumyum_column => 1000)
or 
Sale.where(:yumyum_column => "Customer name") 
both will return the same record.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# Sales Controller
config.columns[:customer].search_sql = "customers.name"
config.search.columns = [:item_name, :customer]  # Search by sale's item_name or customers's name.
```

To show the customer name in the list of results try something like:

```
# Customer model
def to_label
  name
end

# Sales Controller
config.list.columns = [:item_name, :customer]
```

For more info, see the [API: Search page](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/API:-Search)

Answer (score 1):

If you have (and you should have) a `customer_id` in your sales table, then you can query sales with any customer attribute you like with a simple join:

```
Sales.joins(:customers).where(:'customers.name' => :john)
```

which translates to the following SQL

```
"SELECT `sales`.* FROM `sales` INNER JOIN `customers` ON `sales`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` WHERE `customers`.`name` = 'john'"
```